# How to evaluate performance of a new feature in a model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, data-mining, predictive-modeling

I am working on a binary classification where I have 4712 records with Label 1 being 1554 records and Label 0 being 3558 records.

When I tried multiple models based on 6,7 and 8 features, I see the below results. Based on the newly added 7th or (7th & 8th) feature, I see an AUC improvement only in one of the models (`LR scikit` and `Xgboost`).

I also come across articles online that says AUC or F1-score aren't strict scoring rules. We could use `log-loss` metric but it's only applicable for `logistic regression`. but we can't use `log-loss` metric for `Xgboost` or `RF` or `SVM` right? So, is there any common metric which I can use to compare. Am I missing something here?

[image]

Does this mean that new feature is helping us improve the performance? But it decreases the performance in other models?

Please note that I split the data into `train and test` and did `10 fold CV` on train data.

So, how do I know that this newly added 7th feature is really helping in improving the model performance?

**update based on answer**

```
from statsmodels.stats.contingency_tables import mcnemar
# define contingency table
table = [[808,138],    # here I added confusion matrix of two models together (I mean based on TP in model 1 is added with TP in model 2 etc)
         [52, 416]]
# calculate mcnemar test
result = mcnemar(table, exact=True)
# summarize the finding
print('statistic=%.3f, p-value=%.3f' % (result.statistic, result.pvalue))
# interpret the p-value
alpha = 0.05
if result.pvalue > alpha:
    print('Same proportions of errors (fail to reject H0)')
else:
    print('Different proportions of errors (reject H0)')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Informally democracy.**

So how many classifiers did it improve, only 1 than dont add it.

**Formally there are a couple of statistical tests.**

**[Cochran's Q test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran's_Q_test)**

Is a generalisation of the [McNemars](https://machinelearningmastery.com/mcnemars-test-for-machine-learning/) test for comparing Machine Learning models.

or read this formal [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.141.3142&rep=rep1&type=pdf) where they discuss it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. Upvoted. I updated my post with few more info.

Comment: Hi, I was just reading about `mcnemar's test`. So basically we pass our `confusion matrix` as input to this mcnemar's test?.. Which can help compare our two models

Comment: But sorry, these metrics only convey whether models are different or not. I guess they don't say whether they are superior or not. correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Take xgb before feature 7 and after. Apply mcnamara, you will know if this is stat. sinificant difference or not

Comment: Hi, let's say `Xgb with 6 features` produces 84%  auc and `Xgb with 7 features` produces 85% AUC. Now if I apply `mcnamer's test`. I will only know whether they are statistically different or not. So, to know whether that difference is an improvement or not, I have to rely on AUC % right? Because it's from 84% to 85%, it is an improvement and it's statistically different. Am I right in understanding this way?

Comment: No you dont have to. You can modify null hypothesis on mcnamara test to ask wether its bigger or equal than and not the current one were the default null test is wether they are the same one or not.

Comment: Okay. get it. Last question. I can compare for Xgb model with 6 features to Xgb model with 7 features and Xgb model with 8 features. Am I right? It's not necessary to have 3 different classifiers like (RF, Xgb, SVM).

Comment: Most of the time no its not neccessary. BUT, there can be a case when a feature is bad only for one model, so testing it only on xgb will show bad results but in general you should add other features. So i would try svm, mlp, or some other DIFFERENT models (RF is partially similiar) Safe road: use a couple of different ones